# wso2: how to remove the version number from the url path

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm quite new to WSO2. Although I managed to find a quick hack to ignore the version number from the url path when calling my services, I would like to know if there's an efficient way of doing this: /Personal/**1.0.0**/Members?tenantId=1&entityNumber=1

Comment: Which product you are using? Is it WSO2 ESB or WSO2 Api Manager?

Comment: WSO2 Api Manager 1.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From APIM 1.9.0 onwards there is a new feature introduced as "version strategy" where you can provide {version} tag in the context in any place. As an example, if you provide the context as api/{version}/test and in the version field as 1.0.0v it will replace the URL pattern as api/1.0.0/test.

Same like that if you really need to get rid of version number apart from the above answer you can provide a text in the version field since it allows text as well.

E.g., 
 In context -> api/{version}/test and in version -> text will make the url pattern as api/text/test

But please note this is not recommended since version is supposed to use version number. You can use the default url as explained in Abiraman's answer. But since version field number allows numeric and text for a situation like -> 1.0.0v, 1v, 1.0.b you can try this as well.

Comment: Thanks @Ushani, I did try the text ("api/text/test") method, and wasn't quite comfortable with it as I have to keep track of the versions, and like you said, the answe provided by Abimaran is best in my case

Answer (score 3):

Make that API with default version in the Implementation Tab by checking "Make this default version" checkbox. Check [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Create+a+new+API+Version) for more and the below image for how to do it.

[image]

Once you have checked that "Make this default version" option, You can two URLs for the API in the Store like below

[image]

> A default API can be invoked without specifying the version number in
>   the URL. For example, if you mark http://host:port/youtube/2.0 as the
>   default version when the API has 1.0 and 3.0 versions as well,
>   requests made to http://host:port/youtube/ get automatically routed to
>   version 2.0.
>
> If you mark any version of an API as the default, you get two API URLs
>   in its Overview page in the API Store. One URL is with the version and
>   the other is without. You can invoke a default version using both
>   URLs.

Comment: yes @Abimaran, tried it with a couple of services that I have, and its working like a charm